# C++ Transparent image using windows.h / WinAPI

Tags: windows, image, winapi, background, transparent

I'm trying to make a custom title bar/border and I want it to be half transparent. When I load the image it works fine, but as soon, as I make even just 1 pixel from 255 opacity to 254, it just shows a white image.

Help would really be appreciated!

I use the windows.h library.
I use a resource ( .rc ) file to get the location of the images.

Don't think about where im doing things right, it's just for testing. I know it's not very efficient.

The Code!
( or at least the most of it / the important )

```
#include "../resource/resource.h"
#include "../header/Window.h"

#pragma warning(disable : 4244)

/////////////////////////
// Window
//


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

HWND m_hWnd;
POINT wndSize = { 900, 900 };

Window::Window() : m_hInstance(GetModuleHandle(nullptr))
{
    const wchar_t * className = L"Main Window";

    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpszClassName = className;
    wc.hInstance = m_hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON));
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hbrBackground = CreatePatternBrush(LoadBitmap(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BG)));

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    DWORD style = NULL;

    RECT rect;
    rect.left = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) * .5 - (wndSize.x * .5);
    rect.top = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) * .5 - (wndSize.y * .5);
    rect.right = rect.left + wndSize.x;
    rect.bottom = rect.top + wndSize.y;

    AdjustWindowRect(&rect, style, false);

    m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        className,
        L"Chess",
        style,
        rect.left,
        rect.top,
        rect.right - rect.left,
        rect.bottom - rect.top,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        m_hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, NULL); // Remove the default borders

    ShowWindow(m_hWnd, SW_SHOW);
}

Window::~Window()
{
    const wchar_t * className = L"Main Window";

    UnregisterClass(className, m_hInstance);
}

bool Window::ProcessMessage()
{
    MSG msg = {};

    RECT rectBorder;

    HBRUSH colorBorder = CreatePatternBrush(LoadBitmap(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TOP)));

    //BitBlt(GetWindowDC(m_hWnd), 0, 0, 900, 30, GetWindowDC(m_hWnd), 0, 0, SRCINVERT);
    //BitBlt(GetWindowDC(m_hWnd), 0, 0, 900, 30, GetWindowDC(m_hWnd), 0, 0, SRCAND);
    //BitBlt(GetWindowDC(m_hWnd), 0, 0, 900, 30, GetWindowDC(m_hWnd), 0, 0, SRCINVERT);

    while(PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0u, 0u, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        switch(msg.message)
        {
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE: // On mouse motion
            Window::updateWndEvents();
            break;

        case WM_PAINT: // On draw request
            rectBorder = { 0, 0, wndSize.x, 30 };
            FillRect(GetWindowDC(m_hWnd), &rectBorder, colorBorder); // Draw the top border
            break;

        case WM_QUIT: // On quit
            return false;
        }

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return true;
}

/////////////////////////
// Window Functions
//

void Window::resizeWindow()
{

}

void Window::moveWindow()
{

}

void Window::updateWndEvents()
{

}
```

Comment: When does your ProcessMessage function get called? Your PeekMessage loop will exit as soon as there are no messages in the queue. Your're also not handling `WM_PAINT` properly. You need to call `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint`. It's also not clear exactly what you think is going to give you a custom/transparent titlebar. So many things wrong with this code, you may want to obtain a beginner's book for Windows programming.

Comment: @JonathanPotter The line that should make a custom titlebar is "HBRUSH colorBorder = CreatePatternBrush(LoadBitmap(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TOP)));" that's the brush and then it gets painted further down inside the WM_PAINT Message. And may I ask what's the point of Begin/EndPaint? what do they do and do you have an example :D

Answer (score 0):

The alpha channel of a PNG image cannot be loaded using `LoadBitmap`.

It is recommended to use [LockBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-lockbits) with `PixelFormat32bppARGB` in GDI+.